# How to save HTML code from web page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, slds

I want to send email after showing preview. For preview, I am using slds-modal in lightning component. It's layout is as shown in image. Is it possible to save html code of modal content and send it over email?
[image]

ComponentA.cmp

```
<div class="slds-m-around_xx-large">
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <c:EmailPreview/>
                </div>
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Send Email" title="Send Email"
                                      onclick="{! c.sendEmail }"/>
                    <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" title="Cancel"
                                      onclick="{! c.closeModal }"/>

                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
</div>
```

EmailPreview.cmp

```
<aura:component >
 <div>
    <table border = "2">
        <tr>
            <th class="slds-size_1-of-3">Header</th>
            <th class="slds-size_1-of-3">Header</th>
            <th class="slds-size_1-of-3">Header</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
     </table>      
</div>
```

Comment: You should start by reading how to call an Apex method from a Lightning component: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm. Then, you can indeed send an email from Apex.

Comment: agree with @MartinLezer, you can send email by calling Aura Enabled Apex Method,

Comment: Yeah,  but I need email layout to be same as preview layout. I have a java listener which sends email. I just need to save HTML code of this preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but you should be able to use [HTML JS DOM methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_methods.asp) like document.getElementById().innerHTML in your Javascript controller and/or helper to get the HTML string, which you can then pass to your Apex controller to send outbound email.

[See this Apex Developer Guide section](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_email_outbound.htm) for info about the Messaging class and setHtmlBody() method.